# Extending FileAppender in logback - advanced file naming

Tags: java, log4j, logback

### Problem:

I'm converting from log4j to logback and having problems with my custom FileAppender. I'm trying to replicate the log4j behavior I had, where the FileAppender created a new file named ***request_req#_req_type_date.log***

Currently, the logged data is correct, however it's appending to the same file request.log rather than creating a new log file for each travel request.

### Question:

What do I need to change so new request log files get created as opposed to appending to a single log file?

This is my ***logback.xml*** configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="FORM_REQ" class="com.app.package.FormRequestAppender">
        <file>${catalina.base}/APPlogs/formrequests/request.xml</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>  
    </appender>

    <logger name="formRequestLogger" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FORM_REQ" />
    </logger>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />

    </root>
</configuration>
```

This is my custom FileAppender (***FormRequestAppender***):

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;


import ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.*;

public class FormRequestAppender<E> extends FileAppender<E> {

    private static String path = null;


    protected void subAppend(LoggingEvent event) {
        this.closeOutputStream();
        setFileName();
        this.setFile(fileName);     
        this.subAppend(event);
    }

    private void setFileName() {
        if (fileName != null) {
            try {
                String paths[] = fileName.split("\\/");
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                if (path == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < paths.length - 1; i++) {
                        sb.append(paths[i] + "//");
                    }
                    path = sb.toString();
                } else {
                    sb.append(path);
                }
                sb.append("request");
                String reqNum = getAttribute(TRAVEL_REQUEST_NUMBER);
                String approvalStatus = getAttribute(APPROVAL_STATUS);
                String postSubmitType = getAttribute(POST_SUBMIT_APP_TYPE);
                if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(reqNum)) {
                    sb.append("_");
                    sb.append(reqNum);
                }
                if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(approvalStatus)) {
                    sb.append("_");
                    sb.append(approvalStatus);
                }
                if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(postSubmitType)) {
                    sb.append("_");
                    sb.append(postSubmitType);
                }
                sb.append("_");
                sb.append(DateTimeUtil.getDateTimeString(new Date()));
                sb.append(".xml");
                fileName = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                addError("An exception on FormRequestAppender.setFileName - " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And this is the only class that uses it when a new request has been submitted:

```
public class SubmissionService {

    private static final Logger formRequestLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("formRequestLogger");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this subAppend method (try to use @Override annotation to be sure that you are overriding super class method. Is possible to be overloading without intention and with that annotation you won't be able to compile if method is not overriding):

```
@Override
protected void subAppend(E event) {
    setFileName();
    this.setFile(fileName);
    start();
    super.subAppend(event);
}
```

rest of code is same as yours. Is not needed for `append` property to be specified in logback.xml.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't make a difference unfortunately.